# can i subquery from a new table as a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a subquery from table c,d as a column value while outer query is from table a, b. how can i rewrite the query to perform individual calculation for num0 column and den0 column. I'm getting this error. This is not a duplicate of a group function error

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
>   00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

I even tried **select 1 from dual** for the sake of simplicity which also resulted in the above error.
I have tried to join all 4 tables a,b,c,d but since the data is huge, this is taking a lot of time to retrieve the result.

```
select
sum(k.tickets) num0, 1 den0, sum(k.tickets) val0,
(select count(*) from c, d where c.column = d.column) num3, 0 den3, 'SLA' tag3, 'total' num_tag3, 'total' den_tag3, 2 decimals3, 100 multiplier3,
1 num4, 1 den4, avg(decode(k.priority, 'P1', k.mttr * tickets)) val4, 'vale' tag4, '' num_tag4, '' den_tag4, 0 decimals4, 1 multiplier4, 4 order4, '' threshold4, 'value'unit4
from a k, B b
where k.submit_day between from_tz(to_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + numtodsinterval(1491019200000/1000, 'SECOND'), 'UTC') at time zone 'America/Chicago' and 
from_tz(to_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + numtodsinterval(1493524800000/1000, 'SECOND'), 'UTC') at time zone 'America/Chicago'
and k.column_common = b.column_common
```

Comment: or put it in the from clause and cross join to it.

Comment: Have you researched what that specific error means ? You have aggregation functions in the SELECT clause so you must use a GROUP BY on the non-aggregated columns that the aggregation will be against.

Comment: i tried `select 1 from dual`, thinking it might be an aggregate function issue, but its not

Comment: sorry, if I do `max((select 1 from dual)) ` in that place it works.